# Swift - Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'PHFetchResult<PHAsset>'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, phasset, phfetchoptions

After updating the Xcode to 12.3, I'm getting the error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'PHFetchResult'", its was working before as expected in previous versions.

```
func fetchRecentPhotos() {
    
    if !self.recentImagesArray.isEmpty{return}
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        
        if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions){
            if fetchResult.count > 0 {
                self.recentImagesArray.removeAll()
                for i in 0..<fetchResult.count {
                    let asset =  fetchResult.object(at: i)
                    self.recentImagesArray.append(RecentImage(asset: asset))
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if !self.isVideoStarted{
                        self.recentImagesCollectionView.reloadData()
                        self.recentMediaCollectionHeight.constant = 100
                        print("\(Date())fetchRecentPhotos ===== done")
                        if !self.isMultipleSelection{
                            self.setupGesturesForCameraSelection()
                        }
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                        })
                    }
                }
            }else{
                print("you got no photos")
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

is there anyone resolved the issue?

[image]

Comment: is not optional u can directly use     `let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)`

Comment: thanks. that what i have tried and working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a quick look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624783-fetchassets): `fetchAssets` returns a non-optional so you must not use `if let`.

Replace

```
if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions){ ... }
```

with

```
let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
```